# awk to add prefix if not present in field

Tags: awk

I am trying to add a prefix to a field in `awk` if it is not already present. That is if `chr` isn't present before the number it is inserted. However, if it is there it is skipped.
The first `awk` adds the prefix to each `$2` even if it is present and the senond `awk` does skip the `$2` with `chr` in them, but does print `chr` in the `$2` without. Thank you :).

**file**

```
ASPA,17:3483575-3483585
ATM,11:108289609-108289613
ATP7B,13:51937469-51937480
ATR,chr3:142562768-142562773
BAG3,chr10:119670120-119670123
```

**desired**

```
ASPA,chr17:3483575-3483585
ATM,chr11:108289609-108289613
ATP7B,chr13:51937469-51937480
ATR,chr3:142562768-142562773
BAG3,chr10:119670120-119670123
```

**awk**

```
awk -F, '{$2="chr"$2; print}' file
```

**awk 2**

```
awk -F, '$2 !~/chr/{gsub("chr","chr",$2)}1' file
```

Comment: Can a number in 2nd field be negative number? If yes then do you want to have it like: `chr-11` OR like `-chr11`?

Comment: not OP but in other cases these are not reliably "numbers" they are chromosome identifiers so *could* include `X` & `Y` depending on the genome they are from (and who knows what if from a new assembly ...contig73 ...)

Comment: no they can never be -, but as @tomc mentioned you can have chrX or chrY or chrM. Thank you :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} $2 !~ /^chr/ {$2="chr" $2} 1' file

ASPA,chr17:3483575-3483585
ATM,chr11:108289609-108289613
ATP7B,chr13:51937469-51937480
ATR,chr3:142562768-142562773
BAG3,chr10:119670120-119670123
```

Or without using any regex:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} index($2 , "chr") != 1 {$2="chr" $2} 1' file
```

Another solution that might be shortest of all:

```bash
awk '{sub(/,(chr)?/, ",chr")} 1' file
```

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}
{
  split($1,arr,",")
  if(int(arr[2]) || arr[2]==0){
     $1=arr[1] ",chr" arr[2]
  }
}
1
' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** With GNU `awk` using its `match` function which captures values into an array from capturing groups try following code.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/^([^,]*,)([^:]*)(:.*)/,arr){
  if(int(arr[2]) || arr[2]==0){
    arr[2]="chr" arr[2]
  }
  print arr[1] arr[2] arr[3]
}
'  Input_file
```

***3rd solution(Bonus one):*** Just **in case** your 2nd field is having Negative values(integers) and you want to change it Eg: from `-11` to `-chr11` then you can try following GNU `awk` code.

```
awk '
match($0,/^([^,]*,)(-)?([^:]*)(:.*)/,arr){
  if(int(arr[3]) || arr[3]==0){
    if(arr[2]=="-"){
      arr[3]="-chr" arr[3]
    }
    else{
      arr[3]="chr" arr[3]
    }
    $0=arr[1] arr[3] arr[4]
  }
  print
}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  mawk NF=NF FS=',(chr)?' OFS=',chr'
> ```

```
ASPA,chr17:3483575-3483585
ATM,chr11:108289609-108289613
ATP7B,chr13:51937469-51937480
ATR,chr3:142562768-142562773
BAG3,chr10:119670120-119670123
```